# When do I apply R / R-1 complement?

Tags: logic, binary

Given the following question:

- What is the following is the 3-digit 15’s complement representation
  of -251<sub>10</sub>?

How would I know if I should apply R's complement or R-1's complement?

- 15’s complement of base 15 = (15n)<sub>10</sub> – N
- 15’s complement of hexadecimal number = {(16n)<sub>10</sub>-1)} – N

The same question extends to other bases such as 9, would I use 9<sup>th</sup> complement or 10-1<sup>th</sup> complement?